# Unbale to make https call in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make api calls through https protocol but failed to pass through.  The thing is, our backend colleagues changed the linux ubuntu 20 web server from http to https.  Before the change, the same set of apis through http was successful.  So I am now stuck with https call.

During http, here is how I call the api and was successful:

```
String ServerDomain='http://8.8.8.808:8081';

     final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(ServerDomain+ '/cms/district_list'),
       headers: globals.POST_httpHeaders(map),
       body: map,
     );
```

Now I tried with https:

```
String ServerDomain='8.8.8.808:8081';

    var url = Uri.https(ServerDomain, 'cms/district_list', );
    var response = await http.post(url, body: map, headers: globals.POST_httpHeaders(map),);
```

which gives XMLHttpRequest error, please help!

P.S. the https apis work in PostMan

Comment: check ServerDomain , make it https://

Comment: tried, doesn't work either.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest error means a CORS error. Confirm this in the browser's developer tools "network" tab. If so confirmed, go to the server and make sure it is sending the correct CORS headers

Comment: If this is a server problem, shouldn't be all tools give the same of similar error?  But now is only flutter (on Chrome) cannot pass through, while Postman and Chrome (type url directly) are working fine